# How to insert datetime into Mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to insert datetime. ive see many website about datetime in python. ive tried it all. but didnt work in me

```
import numpy as np
import math
import sys
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from datetime import datetime


id_pel = 'PEL0005,PEL0006,PEL0007,PEL0008,PEL0009,PEL0010,PEL0011,PEL0012,PEL0013,PEL0014'
p = [[9,1,7,3,14,3,18,2,22,2],
     [2,2,6,4,4,9,3,3,3,7],
     [13.9769,12.1656,40.047,28.287,25.1415,47.6875,34.269,38.3822,47.6875,19.575]
    ]
result = ['C2', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C1', 'C3', 'C1', 'C3', 'C2']

def insertData(id_pel, recency, frequency, monetary, result):
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='myDB', user='root', password='')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = """
        INSERT INTO clust_result(
            id_pel, 
            recency,
            frequency,
            monetary,
            hasil,
            tanggal_cluster
       ) VALUES (
            %s, 
            %s, 
            %s, 
            %s, 
            %s, 
            current_date
       ) 
        """
        current_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        records = zip(id_pel.split(','), p[0],p[1],p[2], result)
        cursor.executemany(query,records)
        connection.commit()
        print("Inserted successfully")

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert into MySQL table {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")

insertData(id_pel,p[0],p[1],p[2],result)
```

The query works. but in database the `tanggal_cluster` become `2019-11-12 00:00:00`

i expect the result : 2019-11-12 19:12:30

Data Type of tanggal_cluster in phpmyadmin is Datetime.

Comment: try to insert the datetime as timestamp in a test db and see if it inserts and keeps the data as datetime ?

Comment: and if just replace current_date for now() ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet inserted, but still 2019-11-12 00:00:00

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar it worksss!!!! thankyouuu so much

Answer (score 1):

[I know I should be asking this in a comment but I don't have the reputation points to do so.]

Is there a reason you don't just use MySQL to get the date time? By using a function like [NOW()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_now.asp) you can get the current date/time returned as "YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS".

It would be helpful for you to include what your script currently returns and how that is different from your ideal result.